# (Unity) Need to place object at specific coordinates

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, vector, graphics, coordinates

I only recently started using Unity, and converting my pre-made code to it. Now I am trying to make an object appear at a specific coordinates, in 2D.

I'll try to explain. The game has main interface window, with some kind of frame. Game rooms need to appear inside the frame. So, in Unity main window, I place one such room manually, to write down coordinates of the game room. Now, I want to write a script, that will place the object in those coordinates.

Just as example, let's say those coordinates are: (30,40).

To make sure I make myself clear: 30 and 40 are distances between left upper corner of large area and left upper corner of a small area inside.

I tried looking online about how to use those coordinates, and found about Vectors.

That what I was trying to do:

```
 using System.Collections;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using UnityEngine;
 using UnityEngine.UI;

  public class AreaContainerScript : MonoBehaviour
 {
static List<GameObject> SmallAreas = new List<GameObject>();

static Vector2 SmallVector = new Vector2(20, 280);

void DefineSmallAreas()
{        
    SmallAreas.Add(GameObject.Find("areaConfirmLoad"));
    SmallAreas.Add(GameObject.Find("areaConfirmQuit"));
//...
}



void StartAllAreas()
{
    DefineSmallAreas();


    foreach (GameObject thisObject in SmallAreas)
    {
        thisObject.transform.position = SmallVector;
        thisObject.SetActive(false);
    }
}
```

I visually see relevant image (in wrong place) only if I set Vector properties between -1 and 1.

After some trying, I understood, that vector x and y values are supposed to be in a different format, they should be decimals, always between -1 and 1.

How can I convert exact coordinates to this decimal fraction? Or maybe I should use a different approach?

Thank you in advance,

Evgenie

Comment: If i understand you correctly you are unable to position that object correctly on screen?

You can convert world position to screen position and vice versa.
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.WorldToScreenPoint.html

Comment: the other is https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"I understood, that vector x and y values are supposed to be in a different format, they should be decimals, always between -1 and 1."

Only special kinds of Vectors called NORMAL vectors need to have values in this range.  What makes them special is that the LENGTH of a normal vector is always ONE.
So, we know that 1= sqrt(x* x + y* y)  -  which is just Pythagoras's theorem.  (notice that for this equation to be true, niether x nor y can be outside of the range of -1 to 1; try it.)

The advantage to using vectors with a length of 1.0 is that: if you multiply both its components(x and y) by the same number ("scaling" the vector) let's say.. A, then the length of the resultant vector will be, exactly = A.   e.g. A = sqrt(A* x* x + A* y* y)

We can use a similar scaling method to get the two vectors needed to position and size your small room, as a particular fraction of the large room.
Let's say the large room has a position (Xpos,Ypos) and a size (Xsize, Ysize):

1)If we want the small room to be say ... half the size of the large room, we can define the small room size as (Xsize/2, Ysize/2).  (In unity you can just multiply the whole vector by 0.5f)

2)If we want the upper-left corner of the small-room to be located say.. one-third of the way down and across the large room, we would define it's distance from the top left as follows:
`distance vector = (Xsize/3, Ysize/3)`  (we SCALE the size of the large room, by one-third)

3)now we can just add this result to the top left position of the large room-  this is called a vector OFFSET.

```
small room top left location(a vector) = distance(the vector we just computed) + top left of lerge room(a vector)
```

or

```
(x,y)= (Xsize/3,Ysize/3) +(Xpos,Ypos)
```